# Passing proxy settings to a bundled JRE install4j application?

Tags: install4j

We provided an application installed with install4j, with bundled JRE, to one of our customers. This customer needs some proxy settings configured manually for this application.

I tried to put deployment.config file in the JRE's lib directory but it didn't seem to change anything. I couldn't find a relevant vmoptions either.

Is there a way to pass these settings to the app/jre?

Is there also a way to instruct the JRE to open the Java console when it runs?

Thanks!
/Shmulik.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the proxy by setting the VM parameters

```
proxySet=true
proxyHost=...
proxyPort=...
```

and for authentication

```
proxyAuth=true
proxyAuthUser=...
proxyAuthPassword=...
```

You can set them either in a "Run script" in the startup node of the installer action by calling System.setProperty() for the properties or by passing them on the command line like this:

```
-DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=... etc
```

As for your second question (better to ask a separate question on stackoverflow)

> Is there also a way to instruct the JRE to open the Java console when it runs?

I assume you mean a terminal window, which can be done by selecting the "Windows console executable" property of the installer. You cannot change this property on the command line because this sets a static flag in the binary format of the Windows executable furing compilation.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! I passed it on to the developers because the application doesn't seem to have currently a way to use the parameters when passed through vm options.

Answer (score 0):

I created an installer for WINDOWS as well as for MAC. The
application is using an embedded JRE. While the application runs, it's not
able to detect the proxy settings of the network even the option in
the browser is set to be "Auto Detect". But when the proxy settings provided explicitly in the browser, it's able to detect the proxy settings.

Even the proxy settings are not detected when "LAN Settings->Use automatic configuration script" option is selected and points to the .pac file.

Any suggestion, how to provide the proxy settings with BUNDLED JRE and java program can detect those settings without make any further changes in each machine.